# UWP XAML GridView - add whitespace below last item (inside ScrollViewer)

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, scrollviewer

I have a XAML `GridView` showing a lot of items, scrolling vertically. At the bottom I'd like to have some whitespace below the last row but still inside the `ScrollViewer`.

What's the best way to achieve this? Should this be applied to the `ItemsWrapGrid`? If so, can anyone give me an example how to do that?

Comment: Did you try applying Padding to your `ScrollViewer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a padding in your GridView:

```
<GridView Name="myGridView" Padding="0,0,0,180"/>
```